# Cytoscape layout preset with collapseAll and changing layout on expand nodes group

Tags: reactjs, cytoscape.js

I am using cytoscape js with react cytoscape and cytoscape undoRedo and cytoscape expand collapse. On first render I want to have layout by preset(I have all node's positions). It works well but when i perform api.collapseAll() it looks like nodes does not have these positions. Even though groupped nodes have the same position as parent. On expand I want to use cose bilkent layout. Is there a way to do it?

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Cytoscape from 'cytoscape';
import CytoscapeComponent from 'react-cytoscapejs';
import COSEBilkent from 'cytoscape-cose-bilkent';
import undoRedo from 'cytoscape-undo-redo';
import expandCollapse from 'cytoscape-expand-collapse';

const Test = ({}) => {
  const [cy, setCy] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (cy) {

      const api = cy.expandCollapse({
        layoutBy: {
          name: 'cose-bilkent',
          // name: 'preset', I want to have this layout on first render
          animate: 'end',
          randomize: false,
          fit: false
        },
        fisheye: true
      });
      cy.undoRedo();
      api.collapseAll();
    }
  }, [cy]);
return (
    <CytoscapeComponent
      stylesheet={styles}
      cy={cy => {
        setCy(cy);
      }}
      elements={elements}
      style={{ width: '1200px', height: '1200px'}}
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. I made it via setting layoutBy within collapseAll method;)